# Socket lab (localhost on xampp)

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to test my socket connection codes in `php` on my `localhost` with `xampp` on windows but it seems that there can be just one client which is my browser. But I'm trying to test it with different clients. Is there any way to provide some sort of lab for testing these type of connection with different clients?

Answer (score 0):

The closest answer I found is this two extensions for chrome:

[Simple WebSocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/megiodhnhnefnepmelblbmkklimncipa)

[Dark WebSocket Terminal](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-websocket-terminal/dmogdjmcpfaibncngoolgljgocdabhke)

They provide different clients for connecting to your localhost socket server.